# Credit card processing between Magento & Oracle

Tags: magento, oracle11g

We have an oracle erp system through which orders are shipped. Magento is our ecommerce system for web orders, we are trying to find a solution to get the authorization code once a credit card is processed and then send it to oracle from Magento and charge the credit card only when the item is shipped from oracle.

Has anyone implemented such a system and do you have any suggestions to get a credit card information from Magneto to oracle without storing the credit card number?

Thanks,
Aarti

Comment: As per description of your question, I want to know How you connect/implement Oracle ERP with Magento?? Waiting for your reply. Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

There are great number of credit card processing companies out there.  Each company has their own api.

Do you already have your credit card processing in place and you are receiving the auth code?  If you do have your cc processing in place, then you have to look at what data  transport mechanisms from your cc processor to magento and Oracle erp have.  I would start with their respective data export and import facilities.

If you do not have credit card (cc) processing in place, then talk to your bank and existing cc company for your over the counter sales.  You could try eBay, but they tend to be a fair bit more expensive than having a direct relationship with your bank.      you probably would also want to get advice  from your accountant, perhaps see what Google comes up with for your country.